# Erro no reconhecimento de voz em IA python

Tags: python, inteligência-artificial

Ola estou com um erro que ele exibe a mensagem mas não o que eu disse

```
main.py
Ouvindo....
Você disse {'alternative': [{'transcript': 'você disse', 'confidence': 0.88387161}, {'transcript': 'você diz'}, {'transcript': 'e você disse'}, {'transcript': 'se você diz'}, {'transcript': 'você diz isso'}], 'final': True}
main.py
Ouvindo....
Você disse []
```

codigo em Python:

```
import speech_recognition as sr


def reconhecer():
    rec = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as s:
        rec.adjust_for_ambient_noise(s)

        while True:
            try:
                audio = rec.listen(s)
                entrada = rec.recognize_google(audio, language="pt-PT", show_all=True)
                return "Você disse {}".format(entrada)

            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                return "Nao estou te entendendo"
print("Ouvindo.....")
fala = reconhecer()
print(fala)
```

Comment: o que eu disse no microfone ele coloca só []

Comment: Sim, porque o que ele retorna é um dicionário com todas as opções que ele identificou e o nível de confiança. Se você quer exibir apenas o texto precisará acessar esse valor no dicionário.

Comment: então eu mudo o show_all ? e que estou começando agora em python

Comment: Se está começando em python o ideal é começar com o simples mesmo. Aprendendo primeiro a linguagem e os princípios de programação e só depois aplicando num contexto especifico. Você está a tentar conduzir um formula 1 sem nunca ter pegado num carro.

Answer (score 0):

Isso esta acontecendo porque ele te envia todos os dados na variável `entrada` você só precisa pegar o que ele captou do seu microfone dentro do `Dict`, assim:

```
import speech_recognition as sr


def reconhecer():
    rec = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as s:
        rec.adjust_for_ambient_noise(s)

        while True:
            try:
                audio = rec.listen(s)
                entrada = rec.recognize_google(audio, language="pt-PT", show_all=True)
                return "Você disse {}".format(entrada["alternative"][0]["transcript"])

            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                return "Nao estou te entendendo"
print("Ouvindo.....")
fala = reconhecer()
print(fala)
```

```
return "Você disse {}".format(entrada["alternative"][0]["transcript"])
```

---

- [Python Dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)